# Re-read a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I'd like to re-read all Kafka events programmatically. I know there is an [Application Reset Tool](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/), but from what I understand, that requires me to shut down my application. I can't shut the application down in my use-case.

Is there a way to make my application re-read all events on a Kafka topic? Examples or code snippets would be much appreciated. Preferably but not necessarily using Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot re-read topic with Kafka Streams, but with "plain" Kafka you can position consumer to any valid offset.

Something like

```
    final Map<Integer, TopicPartition> partitions = new HashMap<>();
    // get all partitions for the topic
    for (final PartitionInfo partition : consumer.partitionsFor("your_topic")) {
        final TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("your_topic", partition.partition());
        partitions.put(partition.partition(), tp);
    }
    consumer.assign(partitions.values());
    consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions.values());
```

Answer (score 2):

Consumers are required to stop in order to avoid running into race conditions between consumers committing offsets and AdminClient altering offsets.

If you wish to keep the consumer group id, you can use [Kafka Consumer seek APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-) to look for the earliest offsets. Then [AdminClient can be used to alter consumer group offsets](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html#alterConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AlterConsumerGroupOffsetsOptions-).

`kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` implementation should be a good example on how to accomplish this: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/85b6545b8159885c57ab67e08b7185be8a607988/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L446-L469

Otherwise, using another consumer group id should be enough to consume from the beginning, if your `auto.offset.reset` is set to earliest.